# Liquibase Gradle Plugin not recognizing Kotlin Custom Changesets and Resource Files

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, liquibase

I'm currently working on a mixed Java/Kotlin Spring Boot project that uses Liquibase for database migrations. The migration task, configured using a Gradle plugin, runs on every startup. It checks changelogs and applies unexecuted migrations before starting the business logic of the server.

I'm now attempting to integrate a testing process for Liquibase migrations into our CI/CD system. For this i first build a database schema using the current master branch, and then mark all migrations as executed, to simulate how the actual running state of the database would look like, when we apply new migrations to it. For this, I'm using the changelogSync task from the Liquibase Gradle plugin, to mark all changelogs and prevent them from being re-run.

The problem I am facing is that the plugin fails to find any files defined using the `classpath:` notation, which is the case for all my migrations. I was able to circumvent this buy using the `relativeToChangelogFile` notation and using relative paths, but now it's still having trouble with my custom changeset defined a kotlin code in my src folder.

I tried making the `changelogSync` task depend on `kotlinCompile` but it seems to me that there is some general problem with the liquibase runtimes classpath, since it also wasn't able to find the changelogs defined by the classpath.

Below is my `build.gradle.kts` file, showing my setup

```kotlin
plugins {
    ...
}

repositories {
    google()
    maven("https://repo.osgeo.org/repository/release/")
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    // SPRING-BOOT VERSION 3.0.6 DEPENDENCIES
    ...
    
    // LIQUIBASE
    implementation("org.liquibase:liquibase-core:4.19.1")
    implementation("org.liquibase:liquibase-gradle-plugin:2.1.1")

    // LIQUIBASE GRADLE PLUGIN
    liquibaseRuntime("org.mariadb.jdbc:mariadb-java-client:3.1.2")
    liquibaseRuntime("org.liquibase:liquibase-core:4.19.1")
    liquibaseRuntime("org.liquibase:liquibase-gradle-plugin:2.1.1")
    liquibaseRuntime("info.picocli:picocli:4.6.1")

    // OTHER STUFF
    ...
}

liquibase {
    activities.register("main") {
        this.arguments = mapOf(
                "changeLogFile" to "src/main/resources/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml",
                "url" to "jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/<databaseName>",
                "username" to "<username>",
                "password" to "<topsecretpassword>",
                "driver" to "org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver",
                "classpath" to "build/classes/kotlin/main"
        )
    }
}

//tasks.named("changelogSync") {
//    dependsOn("compileKotlin")
//}
```

And here is the output if I try to run aforementioned gradle task

```
Starting Liquibase at 16:57:02 (version 4.19.1 #7641 built at 2023-02-28 18:08+0000)
Liquibase Version: 4.19.1
[2023-06-28 16:57:02] INFO [liquibase.integration] Starting command execution.
SLF4J: No SLF4J providers were found.
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders for further details.
[2023-06-28 16:57:02] INFO [liquibase.executor] Changelog query completed.
[2023-06-28 16:57:02] INFO [liquibase.executor] Changelog query completed.
[2023-06-28 16:57:02] INFO [liquibase.executor] Changelog query completed.
[2023-06-28 16:57:02] INFO [liquibase.lockservice] Successfully acquired change log lock
[2023-06-28 16:57:02] INFO [liquibase.executor] Changelog query completed.
[2023-06-28 16:57:02] INFO [liquibase.changelog] Reading from <myserver>.DATABASECHANGELOG
[2023-06-28 16:57:02] INFO [liquibase.executor] Changelog query completed.
[2023-06-28 16:57:02] INFO [liquibase.executor] Changelog query completed.
[2023-06-28 16:57:02] INFO [liquibase.executor] Changelog query completed.
[2023-06-28 16:57:02] INFO [liquibase.lockservice] Successfully released change log lock
[2023-06-28 16:57:02] SEVERE [liquibase.integration] kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics
  - Caused by: kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics
    at app.<myserver>.server.migrations.<CustomMigrationName>.setFileOpener(<CustomMigrationName>.kt)
    at liquibase.change.custom.CustomChangeWrapper.configureCustomChange(CustomChangeWrapper.java:248)
```

From my understanding, liquibase introduced it's own runtime for the plugin, hence the extra `liquibaseRuntime` notation for the dependencies, so my question is, what do I have to do, to register my custom changesets, as well as the changeset defined in the resources using xml, to the classpath used in this runtime ?

Comment: Okay, so as I was trying to document this in our internal Jira, i got another idea, an this now actually worked, but it looks kinda odd/disgusting to me.
I simply added this line to build.gradle: `liquibaseRuntime("app.vinitor:server")`
Any idea how i could replicate this, but in a cleaner fashion ?